# Redirected to default page in asp.net from sub folder

Tags: asp.net

I have branch folder and admin files are simply placed outer to branch folder.When user login to site,it will check for user name if its admin it will redirect to default page and if its not admin it will redirect to branch/default page.The problem is when i logged to branch folder the url will be www.adi.in/branch/default.aspx.if i removed the branch/default.aspx from url in branch folder ie.www.adi.in when i give like this it redirecting to default aspx that is placed outside the branch folder even though we logged into branch folder.

Comment: use ~ (tild) sign 
This sign represent the root directory of project

Comment: I dont want to redirect to default  page that is placed outside to branch folder from branch folder..

Comment: so you want if user is login then you dont want to redirect him to home page

Comment: Yes.when i gave ww.ad.in it needs to send to login page not to default page of admin.

Comment: are you using master pages for both panel?

Comment: Yes..but different master pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81352/discussion-between-r-p-and-priya).

Answer (score 0):

ok. then check the condition on page load event of your master page with your session variable. Check something like this on your master page

```
if(session["UserName"]!=null)
{
if(session["UserName"]=="admin")
{
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
else if (session["UserName")=="branch")
{
 Response.Redirect("~/branch/default.aspx");
}
}
```

Comment: How it can help for my problem.If i gave adi.bet.in it should redirect to login page always whether it may branch or  admin

Comment: I got a solution by giving the following code in the web config <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="LoginDefault.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>